# Terraform AWS SAML URL provider details key not available in documentation

Tags: terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws

I'm developing a solution where i'm connecting AWS Cognito with SAML Identity provider using terraform.

I have done the entire configuration but i'm not able to find the key for setting up "Metadata document endpoint URL" in terraform.
[image]
The document high level mentions only

- provider_details (Optional) - The map of identity details, such as access token

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_identity_provider

i have researched and found out the key for setting up SAML Metadata using file but not able to provide the url.

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_provider" "identity_provider" {
  user_pool_id  = aws_cognito_user_pool.cognito_user_pool.id
  provider_name = format("si-saml-%s", var.stack_env)
  provider_type = "SAML"

  provider_details = {
    MetadataFile  = "${file("saml-metadata.xml")}" <<< Alternative if we have SAML metadata file
    MetadataDocumentURL / MetadataDocumentEndpointURL / ??
  }

  attribute_mapping = {
    name        = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/<chain>/name"
    given_name  = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/<chain>/givenname"
    family_name = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/<chain>/surname"
    email       = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/<chain>/emailaddress"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have answer yet?
Looking into this myself, but not quite ready to try it yet.

I am assuming assuming currently it will be similar to Cloudformation.

MetadataFile or MetadataURL

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpoolidentityprovider.html

Also the AWS CLI

```
aws cognito-idp create-identity-provider \
--user-pool-id <yourUserPoolID> \
--provider-name=<IDProviderName> \
--provider-type SAML \
--provider-details **MetadataURL**=<MetadataURLCopiedFromAzureAD> \
--attribute-mapping email=http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress,<customAttributeName>=http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of office365 SAML it should be:

```
resource "aws_cognito_identity_provider" "identity_provider" {
  user_pool_id  = aws_cognito_user_pool.cognito_user_pool.id
  provider_name = format("si-saml-%s", var.stack_env)
  provider_type = "SAML"

  provider_details = {
    MetadataURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx"   
  }

  attribute_mapping = {
    email    = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress,CUSTOM_ATTR_NAME=http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups"
  }
}
```